# load old village to new phone

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have been playing Clash of Clans on my iPhone 5. I have town hall 10. Now I have gotten a new Galaxy 5. I am trying to get my old village onto my new phone but it isn't work. When I first launched Clash of Clans on the new phone, it automatically did load a new village town hall 1. I can still launch the old village on my old phone. Is there any way to get my old village to my new phone?